# Try to display infoWindow when click on a list location item in google-maps-react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, infowindow, google-maps-react

my problem is that the package (google-maps-react) has  a default function of showing info window

```
onMarkerClick = (props, marker, e) =>
  this.setState({
    selectedPlace: props,
    activeMarker: marker,
    showingInfoWindow: true
  });
```

and a specific way to call it

```
<Marker onClick={this.onMarkerClick} />
```

if i console.log(ActiveMarker) i get this object on the photo [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTbWI.png).. Can anyone explain what is it?? because i want to call this function with arguments and i cannot retrieve this object in order to pass it in to the other function. i need this because i want to call onMarkerClick inside another function that handles list location items clicks .. Thank you in advance :slightly_smiling_face:

Answer (score 0):

The activeMarker object gives you information about the marker you selected (address, position, etc.). On the example, https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#infowindow, I noticed they have a infoWindow element that shows / hides depending on a property - do you have somewhere in your code that toggles that?

```
<InfoWindow
  marker={this.state.activeMarker}
  visible={this.state.showingInfoWindow}>
    <div>
      <h1>{this.state.selectedPlace.name}</h1>
    </div>
</InfoWindow>
```

You are currently updating the state to capture the marker and selectedPlace. To trigger the infoWindow to popup from another function, all you need is to toggle your showingInfoWindow value. You can also retrieve the marker information since it's now part of your state.

Comment: thank you, but i am using another npm package. It's documentation is this https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps-react

Comment: react-google-maps, google-react-maps - whoops! I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can always pass info to the new function like

```
......
markerClicked(marker) {
   console.log('marker', marker);
   this.setState({
     activeMarker: marker,
     showingInfoWindow: true,
     selected_pin_lat: marker.position.lat(),
     selected_pin_lng: marker.position.lng(),,
   });
}

......
<Marker
  key={index}
  name={pin.type}
  position={{ lat: pin.location[0], lng: pin.location[1] }}
  onClick={(props, marker, clickEvent) => this.markerClicked(marker)}
  icon={
    new window.google.maps.MarkerImage(
      ICONS.mapPinIcon,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      new window.google.maps.Size(30, 30),
    )
  }
/>
......
```